# Displacement map is completely white

Tags: displacement

I have baked a displacement map from a high poly sclupted mesh to a uv unwraped unsubdivided version of it, however the map is completely white and adds very little or even no detail to the mesh, even if I apply more subdivisions than the original mesh. I have tried placing the modifiers in different orders and that dosnt help.
here is the mesh with displacement modifier applied, the displacement map can be seen beside it:
[image]
And here is the high poly mesh the map was baked from:
[image]

Comment: Changing modifiers order won't give anything as you want Displacement to happen once there is enough geometry it to happen; and this will work only if Displacement is after Subsurf (if the latter needed). Although something strange's going on on your screenshots. The high-poly mesh has 4,5 mln. polys; the mesh with displacement (low-poly?) has 18 mln. So what is the purpose of the displacement then if amount of geometry is greater ?

Comment: I ramped the subdivisions up on the other mesh to see if that would help the displacement modifier, as you can see it didnt.

Comment: Remove the modifiers from your lo-poly model. You don't need them to bake a displacement map. Also remember, that displacement mapping does the rough details while normal maps then "produce" (fake) the fine details.